# query mongodb with express and graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

how do we use graph ql with mongo db here is my code with resolvers

```
var resolvers = {
    test:()=>{
        return getproducts()
    },
 }

 const getproducts=()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Product.find({}).exec()
        .then(resp=>{
            console.log("response is ",resp);
            let stringData = resp.toString()
            resolve(stringData);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('error is ',err);
            reject(err);
        })
    })
 }
```

and schema is :

```
test:String!
```

i am converting my response in string , in schema how can we give it the type of Product schema ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getproducts` should return an object matching the properties of your `GraphQL` Schema, I would need more code to answer your question properly but here's a quick fix for your issue, keeping in mind that that `mongodb` Product schema should match the `GraphQL` Schema.

```
var resolvers = {
    Query: {
       getProducts: () => {
          return getproducts();
       },
    },
 }

 const getproducts = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Product.find({}).exec()
        .then(resp=>{
            console.log("response is ",resp);
            // let stringData = resp.toString()
            resolve(resp);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('error is ',err);
            reject(err);
        })
    })
 }
```

#### GraphQL Schema

```
type Product {
   test: String
}

type Query {
   getProducts: [Product] // Query returns an array of products
}
```

Comment: i want to achieve  something like this :https://medium.com/@sarkis.tlt/how-to-use-mongoose-schema-to-generate-graphql-type-ada63a89915

 product is nor graphql type so it can not be pass directly.

Comment: @subhashishnegi can you share your mongoose schema?

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name:{type:String, required:true},
    price:{type:Number, required:true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

Comment: Just to understand, you don't want your graphql schema to match mongodb schema ?